# RXJava. Identify when all obervables inside for loop are finished

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to perform the following. I have a list of transactions which i want to update by making 2 api requests (i am using retrofit2), for each transactions and then saving the result into a database(using the observer). After some searching i decided to use zip operator to combine the 2 requests but the issue that i'm have is that i cannot identify when the whole process is finished to update the UI. Code looks like this.

```
for (Transaction realmTransaction : allTransactions) {

        Observable<Map<String, String>> obs1 = getObs1(realmTransaction);

        Observable<Map<String, String>> obs2= getObs2(realmTransaction);

       Observable.zip(obs1, obs2,
                (map1, map2) -> {
                    Map<String, String> combined = new HashMap<>();
// do some processing and return a single map after 
                    return combined;
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(getObserver(realmTransaction));
    }

public Observer<Map<String, String>> getObserver(Transaction t){
return new Observer<Map<String, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Map<String, String> stringStringMap) {
// update database
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                }
}
```

The observer that i have updates a field of the realmTransaction object.

**My question is how do i get notified when the for loop has ended??**

I would like to sent an event (maybe use EventBust) after the whole process has finish to kick off some other method.

**Thanks**

Also another small question that i have is about the function that i provide inside the zip operator, how can i specify on which thread that function will run on? I would like to use a computation thread for that thats why i put observeOn twice, but I couldnt find an answer anywhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you have a for loop, you should think about `range`, `fromArray` or `fromIterable`. In addition, you may not need the full `subscribe` but `doOnNext()`:

```java
Observable.fromIterable(allTransactions)
    .flatMap(realmTransaction -> {
        Observable<Map<String, String>> obs1 = getObs1(realmTransaction);

        Observable<Map<String, String>> obs2= getObs2(realmTransaction);

        return Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, (map1, map2) -> {
            Map<String, String> combined = new HashMap<>();
            // do some processing and return a single map after 
            return combined;
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext(stringStringMap -> handle(stringStringMap, realmTransaction));
   })
   .ignoreElements()
   .subscribe(() -> handleCompleted(), e -> handleError(e));
```

Comment: The flatmap operator has compilation errors, it seems to require a return statement of an observable but i really dont know what to return there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Returning the _Observable.zip(..)_ seems to be have resolved the issue. Another question that i had regarding the zip operator, are the observables passed as parameters run in parallel or sequential?? Do i have to call _.subscribeOn_ on them to pass the to a newThead to make them run in parallel?

Comment: It depends on where `obs1` and `obs2` run. You may want to apply `subscribeOn` on them instead on the `zip`.

Comment: obs1 and obs2 are basically Observables from retrofit2, they are 2 different get requests and i wanted to executed them in parallel and wait for both of them to finish (thats why i thought about using zip), combine them and use the combined map, as i am currently doing. I wanted to know if they are getting executed in parallel since i dont understand from the code.

Comment: Not likely, apply `subscribeOn` on each of them before zipping them.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd you have been a great help,  hopefully this will do the trick `return Observable.zip(obs1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), obs2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), (map1, map2))...`

Answer (score 0):

Since every thing is being done asynchronously , you can create a local variable outside the loop,say `count` and and keep incrementing it `getObserver` function and later check the count is equal to the length of `allTransactions`.
And about your second question, I think the subscribe thread will be used. You using the 2 subscribeOn, only last one will be used.