# RxJava2 - How to know when all concatMapSingle operations finished on iterating Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the method below:

```
private fun bindUploadPhotos(uploadPhotoCommands: List<UploadPhotoCommand>): Disposable {
    return Observable.fromIterable(uploadPhotoCommands)
            .concatMapSingle { param ->
                requestUploadPhoto.getSingle(param)
            }
            .doFinally {
                onAllPhotosUploaded()
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                onPhotoUploaded()
            }
}
```

I upload photos sequentially. I expect `doFinally` to execute after all photos are uploaded successfully. However, it executes immediately.

I am not a RxJava2 master, so I gladly take your different approaches to achieve my purpose.

Comment: Have you checked that: [RXJava. Identify when all obervables inside for loop are finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736411/rxjava-identify-when-all-obervables-inside-for-loop-are-finished)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onComplete` called when all your photos uploaded. so call `onAllPhotosUploaded` there

```
private fun bindUploadPhotos(uploadPhotoCommands: List<UploadPhotoCommand>): Disposable {
    return Observable.fromIterable(uploadPhotoCommands)
            .flatMapSingle { param ->
                requestUploadPhoto.getSingle(param)
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe ({onPhotoUploaded},{},{onAllPhotosUploaded()})
}
```